# Determine when $\frac{n!-1}{3n+1}$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to find $n$ so that $\frac{n!-1}{3n+1}$ is an integer. Assume that $3n+1$ is prime (there are only finitely many solutions where $3n+1$ is composite).

Comment: How do yo know that there are finitely many solutions with $3n+1$ composite and why this makes the problem uninteresting in this case? Why do you think there are infinitely many solutions with $3n+1$ prime? What is the origin of the problem?

Comment: There was a stack exchange question similar to this one except that it read $\frac{n!-1}{2n+1}$ which can be tackled by modifying wilson's theorem. Note that if 3n+1 is composite there is a non-trivial divisor of 3n+1 at most $(3n+1)^{0.5}$ which is less than $n$ for sufficiently large n but $n! - 1$ is co prime to all numbers less than or equal to $n$

Comment: It isn't true that $3n+1$ is prime exept for a finite number of $n$. In fact if $n$ is odd, $3n+1$ is even and so not prime

Comment: If $3n+1$ is composite and divides $n!-1$.

Comment: I think the problem with $2n+1$ is much more tractable. Computations show that there are 19 primes $p$ up to $10^6$ with $((p-1)/3)!\equiv 1\pmod p$, the largest of them being $p=909,151$.

Comment: Yes that is why I asked this question. Maybe we need to consider a bigger ring and think about a Wilson's theorem analogue.

Comment: @acreativename Are you content with the first few positive integers $n$ satisfying your condition, or do you want to classify those integers ?

Comment: The first few solutions are : $$1\ 1190\ 1406\ 4556\ 8372$$

Comment: Are there infinite such n ? Was there an elegant trick to find the first few solutions?

Comment: @acreativename I only found them by brute force, but if you are interested, I can post the PARI/GP code and the solutions upto $10^6$

Comment: A decision whether infinite many solutions exist, will probably be out of reach, but if we assume that the "probability" of a solution is $\frac{1}{3n+1}$, then we can expect infinite many examples. The largest $n\le10^6$ doing the job is $n=983\ 072$

Comment: For composite $3n+1$, the only solution is in fact $n=1$

Comment: Here is a fact that may or may not be helpful; to solve $\frac{an!+b}{n+d} = z$ where $z$ is an integer $a,b,d$ are fixed; the solution set where $n+d$ is prime is precisely when $n+d$ divides $a(-1)^d+b(d-1)!$